# ansible playbook access first loop variable in second loop

Tags: ansible

I have list of applications paths in a file APP_DIR, need to loop through the paths and run start command.

```
  - name: start
    command: "{{item[1]}}"
    with_nested:
        - "{{ lookup('file', 'APP_DIR').splitlines() }}"
        - [ "chdir={{item[0]}} ./start",
            "ps -aef | grep httpd | grep -v grep"]
```

ERROR: FAILED! => {"msg": "'item' is undefined"}.
Thanks in Advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call item variable in a nested list, you can use your command with a simple `with_item` and a multiline like this :

```yaml
- name: start
  command: |
    ./start
    ps -aef | grep httpd | grep -v grep
  args:
    chdir: "{{ item[0] }}"
  with_items: "{{ lookup('file', 'APP_DIR').splitlines() }}"
```